# Contando elementos de un arreglo

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Un entero  seguido de una secuencia de  enteros. Los enteros de la secuencia denotan las especies de los animales de la carrera y están en un rango de 1 a 100000.

Salida: Un entero que es el número de especies diferentes encontradas.

este es el código que llevo:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n;
    int total = 0;

    cin>>n;

    int arr[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(arr[i] != arr[i]){
            total += arr[i];
        }
    }

    cout<<total;
}
```

Ejemplo de como deberia salir
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Debes rehacer tu código:

1. Las formaciones no deben definirse con una variable para establecer su tamaño, debe ser un valor conocido en tiempo de ejecución. Cambia la formación por un `std::vector`:

   ```
   std::vector<int> arr;

   int n;
   cin >> n;
   arr.resize(n);
   ```
2. Para contar las repeticiones, usa un `std::map<int, int>`.

Por ejemplo:

```
vector<int> arr;

int n;
cin >> n;
arr.resize(n);

std::map<int, int> repeticiones;

for (auto &valor : arr)
{
    cin >> valor;
    auto result = repeticiones.emplace(valor, 0);
    ++result.first->second;
}

for (const auto &[k, v] : repeticiones)
    cout << "El numero " << k << " se repite " << v << " veces.\n";
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBBasMwEDxLr1hSKDZOgpsSConjW1/R9iCUTRCRV0aSfWjJ1@uu5JSmOgjt7MzOrHTfr7RVdJ6mB0PaDkeExrgQPaqulX/YiDo6f490qm@lHIKhM5DqMPRKI4R43EtpKEKnDBWl/JJi1jYMtqC8575IBNpLoQ1B2@Ynd9Yeg/nEgsrE4VG7Hbsk4RKy2mOP0WjjCEOinJyHQg3RweOoLBe7ZFBKwa5wOzeL3GcbkelsNNgIh38T19j1lpcoMncJdZn4VTWT1yfjQ1y1AbUjXlJcfwNwHSLMMd4uSxg/OMf9YA4ktBsiNA0sXi3Q0KF3sEj1JYMQMClMxBkdZ5R/jmO90yIt6zEOnqDey@s0beWmltt8P9V1LZ9f5Lc@WXUO04o/7qCraqN@AA)</kbd>.